# Music Player App - avoid that two music players play at the same time

Tags: android, audio-player, exoplayer, android-7.1-nougat, android-music-player

I am developing a Song Player App using ExoPlayer.
The problem I am currently having is that, on Android 7.x devices, the user is being able to listen to two players at the same time. It seems to be a thing of the new Android versions.

I would like to know if is it possible to avoid this behavior, making the user unable to listen to two players while listening to a media on my app.

Comment: Sorry, @ChrisNeve, I did not understand your reply. By "a thing", I meant that it is only happening on Android 7.0+ devices. Sorry if you misinterpreted it. All I seek is a way to, while playing a media in my app, pause the other apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to manage Audio focus in your application.
You can have a look here :
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-focus.html

> To avoid every music app playing at the same time, Android introduces
>   the idea of audio focus. Only one app can hold audio focus at a time.
>
> When your app needs to output audio, it should request audio focus.

```
AudioManager mAudioManager_ = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener mOnAudioFocusChangeListener_ = new AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener()
        {   @Override
            public void onAudioFocusChange (int focusChange)
            {   switch (focusChange)
                {   case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN:
                        Log.e("DEBUG", "##### AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN");
                        break;
                    case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT:
                        Log.e("DEBUG", "##### AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT");
                        break;
                    case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK:
                        Log.e("DEBUG", "##### AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK");
                        break;
                    case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS:
                        Log.e("DEBUG", "##### AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS");
                        break;
                }
            }
        };


if (mAudioManager_.requestAudioFocus(mOnAudioFocusChangeListener_, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN) == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED)
{   // start play
    // ...
    mAudioManager_.abandonAudioFocus(mOnAudioFocusChangeListener_);
}
```